# underset, tabular and text

Tags: math-mode

Please, there are any way of simplify this:

```
\[
\underset{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots }{\text{N\'umero natural}} 
\left\{ 
\begin{tabular}{ l }
1 \\
\text{primo} \\
\text{compuesto} \\
\end{tabular}
\right.
\]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, `\[
\underset{ \ldots }{\text{N\'umero natural}} 
\begin{cases} 
1 \\
\text{primo} \\
\text{compuesto} \\
\end{cases}
\]`, using the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package.

Comment: What is the significance/purpose of `\ldots`?

Comment: @Mico: It was "1, 2, 3, ...". corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility: use `utf8` input encoding, `stackengine` and `blkarray`. You don't even need to be in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{blockarray}{r\{l}
    & 1 \\%
    \Centerstack{Número natural\\   1, 2, 3,  …}\, &  primo \\%
    & compuesto %
  \end{blockarray}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
  \begin{blockarray}{r\{l}
    & 1 \\%
    \Centerstack[l]{Número natural\\   1, 2, 3,  …}\, &  primo \\%
    & compuesto %
  \end{blockarray}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
  \begin{blockarray}{r\{l}
    & 1 \\%
    \Centerstack[r]{Número natural\\   1, 2, 3,  …}\, &  primo \\%
    & compuesto %
  \end{blockarray}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to set the string `1,2,3,\ldots` below "Numero natural" using `\underset`, I strongly suggest you typeset the numbers in text style rather than the default script style. That said, I think the whole display might look better if do not use `\underset` at all. Instead, either place the two strings side-by-side, or replace "Numero natural" with `\mathbb{N}`. At any rate, I suggest using a `cases` environment for the braced material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\underset{\textstyle 1,2,3,\dotsc\mathstrut}{\text{N\'umero natural}} 
\begin{cases}
    1            \\
    \text{primo} \\
    \text{compuesto} 
\end{cases}
\]

\[
\text{N\'umero natural:\,} 1,2,3,\dotsc  
\begin{cases}
    1            \\
    \text{primo} \\
    \text{compuesto} 
\end{cases}
\]

\[
\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}\colon
\begin{cases}
    1            \\
    \text{primo} \\
    \text{compuesto} 
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two `tabular` environments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{@{}c}
Número natural \\
$1,2,3,\dotsc$
\end{tabular}
\left\lbrace
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
$1$ \\
primo \\
compuesto
\end{tabular}
\right.
\]

\[
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c}
Número natural \\
$1,2,3,\dotsc$
\end{tabular}
\left\lbrace
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
$1$ \\
primo \\
compuesto
\end{tabular}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

You can see that you can get different vertical alignment by using the relevant option in the first `tabular`.

[image]